# Change an AsyncImage into a bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently using jetpack compose to code a pokemon GO like game. I have my markers on my map and I use AsyncImages to get images from the PokeAPI. The problem is I need to give bitmaps to my markers but I don't know how to do. I'd appreciate any help.

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elAdU.png)

I tried to change the Async image as you can see in the screenshot but it's not working like this.

Full code :

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(){
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val height = 200
            val width = 100
            val loader = ImageLoader(this)
            val bitmapdraw = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.charac)
            val smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapdraw, width, height, false)
            val location = LatLng(47.394144, 0.68484)
            Column() {

                MapScreen(location)

                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.1f))
                        .weight(1f, true),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {

                    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pokedex),
                        contentDescription = "Pokeball",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(50.dp)
                            .clickable {
                                val navigate =
                                    Intent(this@MainActivity, PokedexActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(navigate)
                            }
                    )

                    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.fight),
                        contentDescription = "Pokeball",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(50.dp)
                            .clickable {

                            }
                    )

                    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pokeball),
                        contentDescription = "Pokeball",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(50.dp)
                            .clickable {

                            }
                    )


                }

            }

        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MapScreen(localisation: LatLng){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val locationState = (MarkerState(position= localisation))
    val liste = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2)
    GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = CameraPositionState(CameraPosition(localisation, 18f, 0f, 0f)),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
    ) {
        AddPokemons(localisation = localisation, pokemons = liste)
    }
}


@Composable
fun AddPokemons(localisation: LatLng, pokemons: MutableList<Int>)
{
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/132.png"
    pokemons.forEach(){
        
        val randLat = Random.nextDouble(-1.0, 1.0) / 500
        val randLong = Random.nextDouble(-1.0, 1.0) / 500
        val randomLocation = LatLng(localisation.latitude + randLat, localisation.longitude + randLong)
        val locationState = (MarkerState(position= randomLocation))
        val image = AsyncImage(model = url, contentDescription = "pokemon")

        Marker(
            state = locationState,
            onClick = {
                val navigate = Intent(context, Combat::class.java)
                startActivity(context, navigate, null)
                false
            },
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap((image as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true))

        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!"
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Greeting("Mathis")
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code with proper formatting instead of screenshots.

Comment: You can't change AsyncImage to ImageBitmap or Bitmap You can get Bitmap from `rememberAsyncImagePainter.state.drawable.bitmap` when state is success